# Heat, retarded potentials and the arrow of time

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics

In his latest book, Carlo Rovelli explains that, while he presents the action of heating as responsible for the arrow of time, it is however not the only potential responsible. We also have to count with retarded potentials, which apparently share some crucial aspects with heat, which can also makes it responsible for an arrow of time. As he didn't elaborate on this point, could someone explain a bit what he meant by this? Thank you!

Comment: What book is this from? It may be helpful if you add a quotation, rather than paraphrasing.

Comment: Simply insert the problematic sentences here. If it is not on English, then translate it (mentioning that it is your translation).